# MongoDB $inc with dot notation produces error (Atlas Server)

Tags: mongodb

I have the following MongoDB Update...

```
DB.collection('counter').findOneAndUpdate(
       { _id: _id },
       { $inc: { 'events.598398c37a9e22304bb197fa.count': 1 } },
       (e,d) => {
       console.log(e);
    })
```

And this seems to work, with the $inc being effective, but produces the following error...

```
Error: key _events:598398c37a9e22304bb197fa.count must not contain '.'
at Error (native)
at serializeInto (/home/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:731:19)
at serializeObject (/home/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:294:18)
at serializeInto (/home/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:754:17)
at serializeObject (/home/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:294:18)
at serializeInto (/home/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:754:17)
at serializeObject (/home/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:294:18)
at serializeInto (/home/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:596:17)
at serializeObject (/home/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:294:18)
at serializeInto (/home/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:754:17)
```

Any Advice welcome.

Comment: can you provide an example of object (document) you are trying to modify?

Comment: It's pretty much an empty Object, just with _id, so 'events' after the update is a top level Child of the Parent Object (Document).